# How to insert static timestamp in Excel Online?

Tags: excel-online

I am working with Excel Online (browser) because I am working with more people.
I am trying to create a time stamp in a cell (eg. B1) after I write the value in a diferent cell (eg A1).
In the Excel app I could do this with VBA using the Now() command and I would get the Value. for example in Cell B1, after I would write a value in A1 cell.

As Excel online doesn't support VBA I can still user Now() command by programming the Cell I want, with something like this (B1):

```
=IF(A1<>"";NOW());"")
```

I wonder, is there a better way to do this in Excel Online?

Comment: Please note that this will not be a timestamp but a simple display of the current time and date (depending on your formatting), which will continue to update as time passes.

Comment: I understand. So what's the better way to create a time stamp in B1 Cell whenever I insert a value in A1 cell?

Comment: I try to avoid working with Excel Online, so sadly I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [article](https://trumpexcel.com/date-timestamp-excel/) - "Circular References Trick to Automatically Insert Date and Timestamp in Excel", and it also seems to work in Excel Online.

First of all, you need to go to `File > Spreadsheet Settings > Calculation` and switch `Iterative Calculation` to `ON`.

In column B you need to use the following formula which normally throws a Circular Reference error:

```
=IF(A2<>"",IF(B2<>"",B2,NOW()),"")
```

Thanks to `Iterative Calculation` being turned on, `NOW()` function won't re-calculate every time something changes in the sheet.

[image]

However, note that it doesn't work for **updating** the values. For example, if you want to change the value in cell `A2` your Timestamp won't update. You would need to delete `A2`'s value and then update it with the new value.

Comment: I've read about that. Thanks. Can you tell me if it's there a way to store the value of the date? This is, if I delete the A1 cell it will all go away... But it's there a way to store the value of the date after the first insertion in the A1 cell?

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry. As you said, the formula in B2 will automatically return blank once you delete value from cell A2.

Comment: Edit - maybe consider using some other syntax, like "-" / 0 / #N/A, instead of deleting the data. In such case Timestamp won't disappear and your Data Entry won't disturb your calculations.

Comment: I see. The thing is: If I could use macros witb vba It would insert the value of the date in the cell. But by programming the cell I will have a dynamic value on it.

Answer (score 0):

**Paste Values: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>**

When one clicks on the clipboard icon above "Paste" will show a help pop-up:

> Cut = <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
> Copy = <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
> Paste = <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
> Paste Values: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

---

#### Workaround

1. Insert `=NOW()` into a cell
2. Copy it (e.g., with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
3. Paste it **by value** wherever (i.e., click on `Home` > `Paste` > `Paste Values`)